# Changing the data for a ComboBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a ComboBox with data in it and it works how they want:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="MyComboBox" Margin="2, 0, 2, 0" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MySamples}" DisplayMemberPath="SampleName" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MySample}" 
                          SelectionChanged="OnComboBoxChanged" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Arial"/>
```

However, now they want the ItemsSource to be indexed.  So it should be something like:

```
some #: SampleName
```

Is there an easy way to make this change just for the ComboBox drop down without changing the architecture?  I cannot change the List itself since in other areas of the map, it's just the SampleName without the index.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `ItemsSource` is a complex type:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then use the [`DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) property of the `ComboBox` to control what gets displayed. In this case you'd add:

```
DisplayMemberPath="SampleName"
```

to the `ComboBox` definition.

If instead you want to display both the index and name then you'll need to define an ItemTemplate for the ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox ....>
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" />
        <TextBlock Text=" : " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Can I alter DisplayMemberPath on the fly to have an index associated with it as well?

Comment: @JW - do you want to display the index as well? You're question wasn't clear on that.